# Magento2: issue with elasticsuite (elasticsearch7) catalog_product index does not exist yet

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch

Magento 2.4.1 I install elasticstuite on elasticsearch7

When I fire up a category, I get an error:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (LogicException): catalog_product index does not exist yet. Make sure everything is reindexed.

Exception #0 (LogicException): catalog_product index does not exist yet. Make sure everything is reindexed.
<pre>#1 Smile\ElasticsuiteCatalogRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product\AttributeList->getMapping() called at [vendor/smile/elasticsuite/src/module-elasticsuite-catalog-rule/Model/Rule/Condition/Product/AttributeList.php:127]
#2 Smile\ElasticsuiteCatalogRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product\AttributeList->getAttributeCollection() called at [vendor/smile/elasticsuite/src/module-elasticsuite-catalog-rule/Model/Rule/Condition/Product.php:109]
#3 Smile\ElasticsuiteCatalogRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product->l
```

What I do:
restart elasticsearch
bin/magento indexer:reset
bin/magento indexer:reindex

Still the same issue. Can anyone have any solution?

Comment: Look at this page if you found something relevant - https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite/issues

Comment: "When I fire up a category"
What do you even mean?

Answer (score 6):

Have you selected "Elasticsuite" as your search engine. Selecting "Elasticsearch 7" would give you this error [image]

Answer (score 1):

As @Martin said you have to change the search engine.

The other way to change this  is to put in app/etc/env.php

```
'system' => [
    'default' => [
        'catalog' => [
            'search' => [
                'engine' => 'elasticsuite'
            ]
```

And in magento 2.4.6, you may have to put:

```
        'smile_elasticsuite_core_base_settings' => [
            'es_client' => [
                'servers' => 'opensearch:9200',
                'enable_https_mode' => 0,
                'http_auth_user' => '',
                'http_auth_pwd' => '',
                'enable_http_auth' => false
            ]
        ]
```

In default.

And then:

```
bin/magento app:config:import
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps helpful: if you do not change the search engine setting in Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog Search then the catalog_product index will not be generated in ElasticSearch.

Source: https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite/issues/173#issuecomment-321014140

Answer (score -1):

Assuming, you want to use magento's built in 'elasticsearch7' support and NOT smile/elasticsuite ('ElasticSuite) as the search engine.

You can't have elasticsuite enabled if you're going to use Magento's 'elasticsearch7'...

Get a list of all elasticsuite modules, so you can disable all of them:

```
bin/magento module:status

bin/magento module:disable -c Smile_ElasticsuiteAdminNotification
bin/magento module:disable -c Smile_ElasticsuiteCore
bin/magento module:disable -c Smile_ElasticsuiteCatalog
bin/magento module:disable -c Smile_ElasticsuiteCatalogGraphQl
bin/magento module:disable -c Smile_ElasticsuiteCatalogRule
bin/magento module:disable -c Smile_ElasticsuiteCatalogOptimizer
bin/magento module:disable -c Smile_ElasticsuiteTracker
bin/magento module:disable -c Smile_ElasticsuiteThesaurus
bin/magento module:disable -c Smile_ElasticsuiteVirtualCategory
bin/magento module:disable -c Smile_ElasticsuiteSwatches
bin/magento module:disable -c Smile_ElasticsuiteIndices
bin/magento module:disable -c Smile_ElasticsuiteAnalytics
bin/magento module:disable -c Smile_ElasticsuiteRating
```

Refresh everything

```
bin/magento maintenance:enable 
bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
rm -rf var/cache/*
rm -rf var/page_cache/*
rm -rf generated/code/*
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
bin/magento indexer:reindex
find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod u+w {} + && find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod u+w {} + && chmod u+x bin/magento

bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento cache:clean
find -exec chown USER:USER {} +

bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
# or
# bin/magento deploy:mode:set default

bin/magento maintenance:disable
```